# How to change the div content dynamically?

Tags: jquery, html

I have a foreach loop inside a table to display the content from DB dynamically.

```
<table cellpadding="3" cellspacing="0" align="center">

<?php 
    foreach($test as $testcontent){
                    echo  '<tr>';
        echo '<td class="trigger">'.$testcontent[0].'</td>';
        echo '<td class="trigger">'.$testcontent[1].'</td>';
        echo '<td class="trigger">'.$testcontent[2].'</td>';
        echo '<div id = popup style="display:none">
                <div class="Month">
                        <div class="MonthDiv">
                            <span class="MonthText">'.$testcontent[0].'</span>
                        </div>
                </div>
            </div>';
            echo '</tr>';
    }
?>
</table>
```

Function to show/hide the popup is as followed...

```
$(function() {
var moveLeft = 20;
var moveDown = 10;

$('.trigger').hover(function(e) {
  $('#popup').show();
    //.css('top', e.pageY + moveDown)
    //.css('left', e.pageX + moveLeft)
    //.appendTo('body');
}, function() {
  $('#popup').hide();
});

$('.trigger').mousemove(function(e) {
  $("#popup").css('top', e.pageY + moveDown).css('left', e.pageX + moveLeft);
});
```

});

reference: [I used this link for popup](http://creativeindividual.co.uk/2011/02/create-a-pop-up-div-in-jquery/)

The popup shows up but the problem is when i move the mouse over the 2nd, 3rd.... row, only the content of the first row is shown in the popup.
I don't know why.  Can any one help me in this?

Comment: Why show the code for the bits that are working ok?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is because in your code don´t change the content of the div popup.

```
$('.trigger').hover(function(e) {
  // Change the content of popup
   $('.MonthText').html($(this).html());
   // Later show the popup
  $('#popup').show();
    //.appendTo('body');
}, function() {
  $('#popup').hide();
});
```

I hope this helps :)

Comment: On loading the div, i got the output as "March 5, 2012, 9:00 pm". Is there any way to get "March" alone....

Comment: Hi, I tried as you said. But I need some clarificaiton. I have 3 rows and 4 columns. When I mouse over a row, i need to get all the values of those "td". $('.MonthText').html($(this).html()); gives only the value of td which mouse points.

Comment: I tried to assign an id to that particular td and fetch the value as $('.MonthText').html($('#test').html());, but i didn't work.

Comment: Try. put a class on <tr class="line"> and use change $(this) for $(".line").html() this return all the html in the row and this html is all the <td>

Comment: it returns only the content of the first row.

Comment: for all the rows is a simimilar concept. Put a class on <table class="myTable") and change $(".line") for $(".myTable").html()

Answer (score 1):

It looks as though it is because you are using an id to refere to the popup but then having multiple popups means this is incorrect.

JQuery is finding the first element with the id popup and displaying that.

A solution would be to perhaps use the rel attribute and change the popup id to a class. Then you could

```
<td class="trigger" rel="popup-0">Text</td>

<div class="popup" rel="popup-0">Popup</div>

$('.trigger').mousemove(function(e) {
  var rel = $(e.target).attr('rel');
  $(".popup[rel='" + rel + "']").css('top', e.pageY + moveDown).css('left', e.pageX + moveLeft);
});
```

I haven't tested this but it should work. I'm basically searching for a popup with a matching rel attribute to the trigger. This is valid xhtml now and so should work.

Answer (score 0):

Well, it's because you attempt to use multiple elements with the same ID, hence it will mess up your page in unexpected ways. Use class names instead.